# How to assign a variable in a switch statement in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to use a switch statement to assign a new variable some value.

Example:

```
let name: string

switch(index) {
    case 0:
       name = "cat"
    case 1:
       name = "dog"
    ....
}
```

But it is telling me `'name' is declared but its value is never read.` Not sure how to fix this...anyone know the proper way to go about this?

Comment: You need to actually use `name` somewhere (other than assigning values to it)

Comment: Also remember to add a `break`.

Comment: [Here is the tslint doc regarding this rule](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-unused-variable/) and here is the complimentary [eslint rule regarding this rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars), which gives a slightly more complete explanation.  The problem isn't with the assigning-- it's that you assign it but then do nothing with it, which is like writing your name on a nametag then throwing it in the garbage-- if you're not going to use it, why write your name?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a similar question with the answer here:
[How to get return value from switch statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612541/how-to-get-return-value-from-switch-statement)

As far as I know, there is no way to use it like e.g. in Java.